# Chain of doughnut - codechef

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve [this](https://www.codechef.com/problems/DONUTS/) problem since last two days. I am not getting the correct results. 
The solutions which are accepted are sorting the number of chains first. I didn't understand why they do it.
Just the first task is correct. For Second task the answer is wrong and for third time limit exceeds.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--) {
    long n=0;
    int f=0,c=0,cuts=0;
    cin>>n>>c;
    int toJoint=c-1;
    int A[c];
    for (int i =0;i<c;i++)
        cin>>A[i];
    if (c>2){
        for (int i =0;i<c;i++) {
            if (A[i]==1) {
                f++;
                cuts++;
                toJoint-=2;
                if(toJoint<=1) break;
            }
        }
        if (toJoint>0){
            if (f==0) cout<<toJoint<<endl;
            else cout<<(cuts+toJoint)<<endl;
        }
        else cout<<cuts<<endl;
    }
    else if (c==1) cout<<0<<endl;       
    else cout<<++cuts<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make your question valid first please. You can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) how. Also it's always hard to tell, why you're getting a WA with an online code judge, because their inner workings aren't disclosed.

Comment: You have to rethink your algorithm. For `X X X 2` (X >= 2), you may cut the whole chain of 2 to have `X -1- X -1- X`, so answer is 2 not 3 as your answer.

Comment: @Jarod42 is sorting necessary to get the answer right?

Comment: I don't have the solution yet, but I think it is a correct method to sort first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following operations, each of which can be used to link two chains together:

1. Cut a chain (>=3) in the middle (0 less chains)
2. Cut a chain (>=2) at the end (1 less chain)
3. Cut a single donut (2 less chains)

An optimal solution never needs to use (1), thus the objective is to make sure that as many operations as possible are (3)s, the rest being (2)s. The obvious best way to do this is to repeatedly cut a donut from the end of the smallest chain and use it to stick together the biggest two chains. This is the reason for sorting the chains. Even so, it might be faster to make the lengths into a heap, and only extract the minimum element as many times as we need to.

Now to the question: your algorithm only uses operation (3) on single donuts, but doesn't try to make more single donuts by cutting donuts from the end of the smallest chain. And so as Jarod42 points out, with
counterexample, it isn't optimal.

---

I should also point out that your use of VLAs

```
int A[c];
```

is an non-standard extension. To be strict, you should use `std::vector` instead.

---

For completeness, here's an example:

```
std::sort(A.begin(), A.end());

int smallest_index = 0;
int cuts = 0;

while (M > 1)
{
    int smallest = A[smallest_index];
    if (smallest <= M - 2)
    {
        // Obliterate the smallest chain, using all its donuts to link other chains
        smallest_index++;
        M -= smallest + 1;
        cuts += smallest;
    }
    else
    {
        // Cut M - 2 donuts from the smallest chain - linking the other chains into one.
        // Now there are two chains, requiring one more cut to link
        cuts += M - 1;
        break;
    }
}

return cuts;
```

(*disclaimer:* only tested on the sample data, may fail in corner-cases or not work at all.)